# Getting Frequent Outgoing SMS

Tags: android, cursor, sms

In an android application, I  want to access the contacts to whom messages are sent most frequently in a particular period. By using servives and broadcast receiver, I have accessed outoging sms details: contact, time, no of messages sent(depending on length of message). Now I want to to get count of each contact appearing in a cursor then adding up its (no. of messages) and then sort the results giving most frequent outgoing messages and contacts.

Comment: then what is the question ?

Comment: Show us the code you have so far. Tell us where you're getting stuck. Don't expect us to write everything for you.

Comment: The question is how to get count of a particular record (each contact) in cursor ?

Comment: I am not expecting you people to write everything for me. I just want you to explain that is my logic correct and is there any method through which we can find no. of occurances of a record in a cursor ?